# Generating in Matlab a "modified" diagonal matrix

Tags: matlab

I want to construct a matrix `A` in Matlab of dimension `w x (m*w)` where

*each row is full of zeros except `m` consecutive `ones` that shift towards the right hand side as we move down to the rows.*

Few examples can clarify

```
w=3,m=4
A=[1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
```

or

```
w=3, m=3
A=[1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
```

or

```
w=2, m=3
A=[1 1 1 0 0 0;
   0 0 0 1 1 1]
```

I can't see how to proceed and any hint would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Start with a loop over the rows of the matrix. Given a row number `i` and `m` you should be able to find a relationship between `i`, `m`, and the start and end indices of the vector of ones in the row and use simple [indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85544).

Comment: I would prefer a vectorised version.

Comment: Why vectorized? Is your loop too slow? Don't optimize until you've profiled! BTW: MATLAB is a lot faster with loops today than even a few year ago. Vectorizing doesn't always yield the fastest code any more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Step 1. Simplify the problem

If you write the *"modified diagonal matrix"* you are asking about as a row vector it will always look like the following

```
% 1 ... 1 0 ... ... 0 ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... 1 ... 1
% m ones   m*w zeros    w-1 times the same as before   m ones
```

#### Step 2. Think how to solve the simplified problem

1. The fundamental unit you need is a vector of `m` ones followed by `m*w` zeros;
2. Once you have built such vector, you need it to be repeated `w` times, MATLAB already knows [how to do that](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html);
3. The only thing you miss are the trailing ones: append them;
4. Now that the vector you were looking for is completed, you need to turn it into a matrix. MATLAB already knows [how to do this](https://it.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html) too.

---

### Final code

Once you understood the above steps, the final behaviour can be achieved even with a one-liner

```
>> m = 4; w = 3;
>> vec2mat([repmat([ones(1, m) zeros(1, m*w)], 1, w-1) ones(1, m)], w*m)

ans =

     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
```

---

### About speed

It's true, for loops aren't so slow anymore. I timed my one-liner solution, the trivial for loop and [Luis Mendo's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48715301/5955745) with `eye()` and `repelem()`.

<sub>*Click on images to zoom*</sub>

[image: for loop]
[image: for loop 2]

[image: my solution]
[image: my solution 2]

[image: eye() and repelem()]
[image: eye() and repelem() 2]

<sup>*Tested on the same machine, with MATLAB R2018a.*</sup>

As you can see, as long as `m` and `w` are quite small, even if you could point out some differences in speed, them won't be noticeable to humans.

Anyway if you are going to work with bigger matrices, it becomes quite obvious which solution is the best.

Comment: Have you timed this solution and a loop? This one seems to be slower, at least in Octave, even counting the time for preallocation.

Comment: @beaker: Indeed, loops are no longer slow in MATLAB. And a loop is easier to read than convoluted vectorized code like this. Still, +1 for good explanation and a clear answer.

Comment: @beaker Just added some speed tests.

Comment: Good stuff, @Marco!

Answer (score 4):

Here are some approaches:

- Using [`eye`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eye.html) and  [`repelem`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html):

  ```
  A = repelem(eye(w), 1, m);
  ```
- Using `eye` and indexing:

  ```
  A = eye(w);
  A = A(1:w, ceil(1/m:1/m:w));
  ```
- Using `eye` and [`kron`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html):

  ```
  A = kron(eye(w), ones(1,m));
  ```
- Using [singleton expansion](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

  ```
  A = bsxfun(@eq, (1:m).', ceil(1/m:1/m:w)); % Or A = (1:m).'==ceil(1/m:1/m:w);
  ```